# Scraping non-absolute URL

Tags: php, html

I am trying to scrape [www.weather.bm](http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp). I want all 10 radar images, but I can only get one (the image updates regularly) and it's not a absolute image url. I was hoping I could use the image as a image slideshow like the link but dont know how. Also, how can I remove `images/Radarlegend.png`? I just need the radar images.

Here is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp');
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
echo $element->src . '<br>'
```

My output is:

```
<div id="main">
images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1556.jpg<br>images/Radarlegend.png<br></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $localOffset = "+2 Hours"; //change this to your local offset from the image times you need. for me (CST) it's 2 hours.....
    $start=  strtotime("-90 Minutes " . $localOffset); // go back 90 minutes (The limit of the available images)
    $start=($start-($start % (600))+(60*6)); //go to the next earlier 6 minute mark (all images appear to be at the 6 minute mark))appear to be at the 6 minute mark))
    for($x=1;$x<=9;$x++){
        $DateTime = date("Y-m-d-Hi", $start); // set the image time we want.
        $fName = ("http://www.weather.bm/images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-$DateTime.jpg"); // set the filename
        echo" $min <img src='$fName' alt='$fName'/><br/>"; // echo (or add to a stack or variable...) your image node
         $start+=(600);//add 10 minutes
    }
```

Comment: do you mean http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp? if yes you can see that it is animated (above 1of10, 2of10 and runs on 10 images view source and you can see the link of the images in a javascript (non absolute ex.'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1506.jpg'). I can only get one image which is the the initial image, I need to get the source of the image (with the domain and path ex.http://www.weather.bm/images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1456.jpg) and make a slideshow of those images just like on the link I gave.

Comment: you can review the code by goinf to http://api.fatherstorm.com/test and clicking on your question# 4597854 . from there you can see the code in action as well as see the source code

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of all ten images is in the JavaScript (formatting changes mine):

```
radarFileNames = new Array(
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1446.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1456.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1506.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1516.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1526.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1536.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1546.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1556.jpg', 
    'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1606.jpg');
```

A simple search through for the line containing `radarFileNames = new Array` will return this line. Then you can extract the URLs with two [`preg_split()`s](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php): first on `\(|\)`, then split the second token on `', '`. Finally, prefix `http://www.weather.bm/` to the URLs.

Comment: can you show me the code I'm just learning as I go on studying the code users kind enough advices me, I have been studying php on and off and have no idea how to implement what you have wrote sorry, your help is much appreciated thanks