# scraping javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I had a problem with scraping a site http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp, Fatherstorm [gave me a great solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597854/scraping-non-absolute-url/4597895#4597895) but it had some minor bugs in regards to start time and number of images source sometimes gives 9 or 10 but the code was set to ten.

On the other hand one person (marcog) gave me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597854/scraping-non-absolute-url/4597980#4597980):

> "A simple search through for the line containing radarFileNames = new Array will return this line. Then you can extract the URLs with two `preg_split()`s: first on `\(|\)`, then split the second token on `', '`. Finally, prefix `http://www.weather.bm/` to the URLs."

I was hoping if someone can show me the code he was talking about. I like to learn this kind of stuff but I just don't have someone to teach me. I hope you guys could help

javascript array:

```
radarFileNames = new Arra(     
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1446.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1456.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1506.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1516.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1526.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1536.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1546.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1556.jpg',      
'images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-2011-01-04-1606.jpg'
```

also would it be possible to output the img inside ul li /li /ul which has it own class  (ul class li class)

Im also using simple html dom parser but I can't get the images only the loaded images is outputed

here is the sample using fatherstorm code
http://j2sdesign.com/rgw/article/20101222/NEWS01/712229951/0/example/r1.php

my code from fatherstorm

```
?php
        $localOffset = "+2 Hours"; //change this to your local offset from the image times you need. for me  it's 1 hours.....
        $start = strtotime("-100 Minutes " . $localOffset); // go back 90 minutes (The limit of the available images)
        $start = ($start - ($start % (600)) + (60 * 6)); //go to the next earlier 6 minute mark (all images appear to be at the 6 minute mark))
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
            $DateTime = date("Y-m-d-Hi", $start); // set the image time we want.
            $fName = ("http://www.weather.bm/images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-$DateTime.jpg"); // set the filename
            echo" <center>$DateTime</center> <img class='radarImg' src='$fName' alt='$fName'  title='$fName'/><br/."; // echo (or add to a stack or variable...) your image node
            $start+= ( 600); //add 10 minutes


        }
        ?
```

mario do you mean 
like this:

```
<?php
        $localOffset = "+2 Hours"; //change this to your local offset from the image times you need. for me  it's 1 hours.....
        $start = strtotime("-100 Minutes " . $localOffset); // go back 90 minutes (The limit of the available images)
        $start = ($start - ($start % (600)) + (60 * 6)); //go to the next earlier 6 minute mark (all images appear to be at the 6 minute mark))
        for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
            $DateTime = date("Y-m-d-Hi", $start); // set the image time we want.
            $fName = ("http://www.weather.bm/images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-$DateTime.jpg"); // set the filename
            echo" <center>$DateTime</center> <img class='radarImg' src='$fName' alt='$fName'  title='$fName'/><br/."; // echo (or add to a stack or variable...) your image node
            $start+= ( 600); //add 10 minutes
        $html = file_get_contents('http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp'); preg_match('/radarFileNames = new Array\((.+?)\);/ims', $html, $m); $files = explode(",", $m[1]);

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: I don't really see a question here. Why don't you just ask marco for clarification?

Comment: -1, this is a gimme teh codez post.

Answer (score 1):

Read the PHP manual on regular expressions. In this case it's as simple as:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp');
preg_match('/radarFileNames = new Array\((.+?)\);/ims', $html, $m);
$files = explode(",", $m[1]);
// then output <img>s
```

The explode() is easier here than preg_split. But then requires a `trim()` on each filename in the array, and a second `trim($filename, "'")` to get rid of the enclosing quotes.

Comment: Where can I insert this code Im using

Comment: Where can I add your code I have edited my post and added my code not that your spoon feeding me but I just have no idea on what to do thanks for the help. Or do you mean I should use simplehtmldon parser instead?

Comment: @cooldude: that's for the extraction. does not belong into the workaround code. well, see edit. no simplehtmldom parser necessary.

Comment: mario can you check my code above I added your code thanks

Comment: @cooldude: Uhm, no. Doesn't mix. Don't monkeypatch magic code snippets. Please read a beginners book. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772349/what-is-a-good-online-tutorial-for-php

Comment: I tried using you code only enclosing it in php ? but it displayed a blank page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//not tested
var len=radarFileNames.length, links='';

for(var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var links = links + '<a href="radarFileNames[i]">'+radarFileNames[i] + '</a>';
}

document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = links;
```

Comment: thank you for your help but Where can I put this code and where do I put the url for the site to be extracted thanks