# Scraping a dynamic weather slideshow

Tags: php, html, css

I am making a weather page and I would need to screen scape the radar image on http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp just the radar images. Fatherstorm has help me before and given me a php script it worked but with some bugs.

```
$localOffset = "+2 Hours"; //change this to your local offset from the image times you need. for me (CST) it's 2 hours.....     
$start=  strtotime("-90 Minutes " . $localOffset); // go back 90 minutes (The limit of the available images)     
$start=($start-($start % (600))+(60*6)); //go to the next earlier 6 minute mark (all images appear to be at the 6 minute mark))appear to be at the 6 minute mark))     
for($x=1;$x<=9;$x++){         
$DateTime = date("Y-m-d-Hi", $start); // set the image time we want.         
$fName = ("http://www.weather.bm/images/Radar/CurrentRadarAnimation_100km_sri/100km_sri-radar-  $DateTime.jpg"); // set the filename         
echo" $min <img src='$fName' alt='$fName'/><br/>"; // echo (or add to a stack or variable...) your image node          
$start+=(600);//add 10 minutes     }
```

Here are the problems:
most of the time some images and discription is not showing due to different time.
the script has 10 images but some times the site only displays 9 or 8.

I need a script that could scrape the images put it in a div ul li so I can animate it like in the original site(I mean the slideshow effect) or make it's path absolute don't know how it would help but I sure want to know how to do that also. The weather sites images is in a javascript array which I am not familliar.

I need the whole script so I can study it before using it so I can learn in the process.

Comment: so you are having trouble stealing another site's content for your own site?

Comment: try this: <?php header('Location: http://www.weather.bm/radarMobile.asp'); exit; ?>

Comment: Comments like "I know I need to learn this... but can you do it for me anyways because I need it now" probably won't get you far in your career.

Comment: actually it's not stealing cause we will advice them about the screen scraping once everything is ok.

Comment: jesse im doing self study on javascript and php but the problem is I just had this proj and needs this script badly I can read some codes but not understand all of them. thats why im asking for the code since this is the way I learn looking at real life codes =)

Comment: dqhendricks thank you for your share but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

I've already given you [a working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648400/scraping-javascript-array/4648633#4648633). You are unable to use it because you seemingly don't comprehend how PHP works. If so, you should consider paying a freelancer to do your coding and script setup. Stackoverflow is not a for-free coding forum - and people are much less inclined to help if people don't even bother to upvote or accept answers.

Comment: Sorry to be an annoyance mario and thanks for your help I would be considering your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think its NOT OK to screen scrape. It may be OK to use API if they have one, but if they don't provide API Or XML feed for what you need, then you may be violating some copyrights by copying their images, even if it's a radar map.

Proceed at your own risk but remember that it's possible that they will find out and take legal actions.

Comment: yes I am aware of that as you can see with my response above. we will not lunch the scrape without proper approval from the weather site we will coordinate with them first. This is not for my personal site. They don't have any api or xml feed which I could use. Thanks =)